# Adding callbacks (interactive inputs) to page container in plotly dash multi pages app

Tags: python, callback, plotly, data-analysis, plotly-dash

### Context:

I am working on an app with **multi pages** feature in **Plotly Dash** that uses this schema:
|`app.py`
| `pages`|
| `games_`*`dashboard.py`
|
|`channels_dashboard.py`
|
| *`videos_dashboard.py`

The project is talking about youtube gaming analysis (videos, channels, comments) data and each file of the pages folder file contains layout in a layout variable and  some callbacks that are also in a variable here's some example code:

```
 layout = html.Div(children= [

    html.Center(children= html.H1(children= ["Analysis for specfic", html.Span(
        " Games ", style= {"color": THEME_COLORS[1]}), "Videos"])),

    dcc.Graph(id= "video_stats_per_game",
              figure= video_stats_per_game.update_layout(width= 1240, height= 500),
              style= {'position': 'absolute', 'border': f'2px solid {THEME_COLORS[0]}','left': '10px',
                      'display': 'inline-block'}),

    html.Div(["Choose a game:",
        dcc.Dropdown(GAMES, "Minecraft" ,id= "game_dropdown")],
                     style= {'top': '600px', 'position': 'absolute', 'display': 'inline-block',
                            'width': '1230px'}), #Bla bla bla
```

and here's the callback varible for the same file:

```
callback_1 = [Output('duration_vs_view', 'figure'), # this `duration_vs_view` is a plot name.
             [Input('game_dropdown', 'value')]]

def duration_vs_view(value): # Some unreadable code ...
 


callback_2 = [Output('stats_growth', 'figure'),
              [Input('game_dropdown', 'value')]]

def stats_growth(value): # bla bla bla


callbacks = callback_1 + callback_2 + callback_3
```

### The problem:

Now what I want to do is implement the callbacks into my `app.py` `page_container` and here's some code from `app.py` :

```
# --------------------Creating the main app----------------------
app = Dash(__name__, use_pages=True,
           external_stylesheets= EXERNAL_STYLESHEETS)

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Center(html.H1([html.Span("Youtube",
                                  style= {"color": THEME_COLORS[1]}), ' gaming analysis'])),
    
    html.Button('Channels dashboard', id='channels_dashboard_button'),
    
    html.Button('Games dashboard', id='games_dashboard_button'),
    
    html.Center(html.Button('Videos dashboard', id='videos_dashboard_button',)),
    
    html.Div(id='page-content', children=dash.page_container)])
# ---------------------------------------------------------------


@app.callback(Output('page-content', 'children'),
              [Input('channels_dashboard_button', 'n_clicks'),
               Input('games_dashboard_button', 'n_clicks'),
               Input('videos_dashboard_button', 'n_clicks')])

def display_page(channels_clicks, games_clicks, videos_clicks):
    
    if channels_clicks:
        return (pages.channels_dashboard.layout,
               pages.channels_dashboard.callbacks)
    
    
    elif games_clicks:
        return (pages.games_dashboard.layout,
               pages.games_dashboard.callbacks) # ...

    else:
            return ''
```

### The Error:

The plotly dash app returns a `callback` error when I click on any button that leads me to a dashbord with callbcks and here's the error message:

```
dash.exceptions.InvalidCallbackReturnValue: The callback for `<Output `page-content.children`>`
                returned a value having type `tuple`
                which is not JSON serializable.


The value in question is either the only value returned,
or is in the top level of the returned list,
```

### Expectation:

I expected that I will get the dashboard just as fine as I was running them without the muli pages functionality  (I used before the normal call back way for single variables)

### At last but not least:

please if you can help me by telling me a totally another way please do that like to use links to each dashboard or something and if you have any idea about how can I fix this please also do that if the problem needs more code or screenshots to put also tell me,**Thanks in advance**

Comment: As the error is saying you can't return a tuple for output `<Output `page-content.children`>`. You can return the layout to update page-content.children, but not also the callbacks.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question, but it seems this is kinda working against the idea of the pages feature. Why put the inputs and outputs of different callbacks in variables and use these in a callback in `app.py`? Why not just register callbacks specific to a page in that page?

Comment: But what do you mean by `register callbacks` to a specific page all I want is to make the main page refers to the three others and if there is another way I can do **Without rewriting callbacks** please tell me I was in the first looking for a way that works as links to each page without the main page to reder with them so if this is possible tell me how please because I am stuck on this for long time @5eb

Comment: With register I just mean define the callback function specific to a page in that page file. Only difference would be that you need to use `@callback` instead of `@app.callback` (or import app in page). I'm still not sure I understand the question fully, but I can write an answer with an example of what I mean if you want.

Comment: Please if you can give me an example do that if that because I am stuck with this problem for a long time. (If that won't disturb you )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the `InvalidCallbackReturnValue` exception you got is because return statements like this:

```
return (pages.channels_dashboard.layout, pages.channels_dashboard.callbacks)
```

For your `Output`: `Output('page-content', 'children')` a valid return value could be:

```
return pages.channels_dashboard.layout
```

But you can't setup the page callbacks this way.

---

I think your `display_page` callback, the passing of layout and callback variables are all unnecessary. I think it's working against the dash pages feature.

You can implement the callbacks in the pages (.py files) themselves.

Here's an example of a simple page with a callback:

```
# File: pages/page1.py

from dash import html, callback, Input, Output, register_page

register_page(__name__)

layout = html.Div([
    html.Button(id="page1-input", children="Click me"),
    html.Div(id="page1-output")
])


@callback(
    Output("page1-output", "children"),
    Input("page1-input", "n_clicks")
)
def update_city_selected(n_clicks):
    return n_clicks
```

Instead of using inputs like `Input('channels_dashboard_button', 'n_clicks')` to go to a certain page you can just use links, no callback required:

```
dcc.Link("Link", href="/page1")
```

If you need the link to look/act like a button you can wrap a button in a link.

Example `app.py`:

```
from dash import Dash, html, dcc
import dash

app = Dash(__name__, use_pages=True)

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div(
        [
            html.Div(dcc.Link(f"{page['name']} - {page['path']}", href=page["relative_path"]))
            for page in dash.page_registry.values()
        ]
    ),
    dash.page_container
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: Thank you you are a lifesaver your answer is working correctly for me.

Comment: But can you please tell me how now I can put an `image` argument or `title` argument to `dash.register_page` function in `app.py` file or is this not even possible

Comment: Why do you want to do that in `app.py`? In the example in my post I call `register_page` inside the page file so you can pass these arguments there.